# Can you accelerate torch DL training on anything other than "cuda" like "hip" or "OpenCL"?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, opencl

I've noticed that `torch.device` can accept a range of arguments, precisely `cpu`, `cuda`, `mkldnn`, `opengl`, `opencl`, `ideep`, `hip`, `msnpu`.

However, when training deep learning models, I've only ever seen `cuda` or `cpu` being used. Very often the code looks something like this

```
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device("cuda")
else:
    device = torch.device("cpu")
```

I've never seen any of the others being used, and was wondering if they can be used and how. The latest MacBooks with an AMD graphic card I believe should be able to use `"hip"`, but is that true? And will the training speed be similar to that of using one CUDA GPU? If not, what is the point in `torch.device` accepting so many options if they cannot actually be used?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to use a GPU for deep learning there is selection between CUDA and CUDA...

More broad answer, yes there is AMD's hip and some OpenCL implementation:

1. The is hip by AMD - CUDA like interface with ports of pytorch, hipCaffe, tensorflow, but

   - AMD's hip/rocm is supported only on Linux - no Windows or Mac OS support by rocm provided
   - Even if you want to use Linux with AMD GPU +  ROCM, you have to stick to GCN desrete devices (i.e. cards like rx 580, Vega 56/64 or Radeon VII), there is no hip/rocm support for RDNA devices (a year since a release) and it does not look to be any time soon, APUs aren't supported as well by hip.
2. Only one popular frameworks that supports OpenCL are Caffe and Keras+PlaidML. But

   - Caffe's issues:

     - Caffe seems have not being actively developed any more and somewhat outdated by todays standard
     - Performance of Caffe OpenCL implementation is about 1/2 of what is provided by nVidia's cuDNN and AMD's MIOpen, but it works quite OK and I used it in many cases.
     - Latest version had even grater performance hit https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/6585 but at least you can run a version that works several changes behind
     - Also Caffe/OpenCL works there are still some bugs I fixed manually for OpenCL over AMD. https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/6239
   - Keras/Plaid-ML

     - Keras on its own is much weaker framework in terms of ability to access lower level functionality
     - PlaidML performance is still 1/2 - to 1/3 of optimized NVidia's cuDNN & AMD's MIOpen-ROCM - and slower that caffe OpenCL in the tests I did
     - The future of non-TF backends for keras is not clear since 2.4 it requires TF...

Bottom line:

1. If you have GCN discrete AMD GPU and you run Linux you can use ROCM+Hip. Yet it isn't as stable as CUDA
2. You can try OpenCL Caffe or Keras-PlaidML - it maybe slower and mot as optimal as other solutions but have higher chances of making it work.

**Edit 2021-09-14:** there is a new project dlprimitives:

https://github.com/artyom-beilis/dlprimitives

that has better performance than both Caffe-OpenCL and Keras - it is ~75% performance for training in comparison to Keras/TF2, however it is under early development and has at this point much more limited set of layers that Caffe/Keras-PlaidML

The connection to pytorch is work in progress with some initial results: https://github.com/artyom-beilis/pytorch_dlprim

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this project